# React Hooks setInterval with dependency trigger multiple interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useEffect with setInterval who refresh each seconds data depending on an user id

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      refetchUserId(userId);
    }, 1000);
 
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [userId]);
```

But when my userId change (with a `setState`) the interval is not cleared and i have a lot of getUserId fired

How to fix this

Thanks

Comment: So you  want it to fire once? Why not use setTimeout?

Comment: Remove from dependencies your **userId**. Because when you put **getUserId(userId)** in `setInterval` it's re-render itself and doesn't require dependencies .

Comment: But i need to trigger a new setInterval when userId changes and remove the previous one